# Html component throws an exception

Tags: html, flutter, exception, render

I am trying to render a HTML code taken from the web. The Code is the following:

```
Material(
  child: Scaffold(
    extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
    appBar:
      StatusBar(title: title, iconLeft: iconLeft, iconRight: iconRight).build(context),
    body: Flex(direction: Axis.vertical, children: [
      Flexible(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              left: padding,
              right: padding,
              top: padding + kToolbarHeight + MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top, bottom: padding),
            child: Column(
              children: [Html(data: "someHtmlCode")],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ]),
  ),
);
```

Actually it works for some HTML data, but for the following snippet/example it does not:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr>
        <td height="70" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;">
            <a name="1"/>&nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
            <tr>
                <td style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;">sdfsd</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="20" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The error says:

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
LayoutBuilder does not support returning intrinsic dimensions.

Calculating the intrinsic dimensions would require running the layout callback speculatively, which might mutate the live render object tree.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Html
...
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderLayoutGrid#b5a0d relayoutBoundary=up31 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
RenderObject: RenderLayoutGrid#b5a0d relayoutBoundary=up31 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found [this](https://github.com/Sub6Resources/flutter_html/issues/589). Nested Tables are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your *Html(data: "someHtmlCode")* in a **SizedBox** or **Container** widget and set a fixed height of 400.